# Excel numbers are converted to exponential form

Tags: ssis

I have a column with mixed datatype number and string. I set IMEX=1 and included header so that every value gets treated as string. But still SSIS is importing large numbers in exponential form. Is there a way to approach this problem?

Problematic source row

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5

5.65679E+16 2196    Yes MD  3   4 as is
```

but the actual value in Excel 1st column is 56567876998768900

[image]

Comment: Can you please put sample source data?

Answer (score 0):

your appraoach is right to treat the data to string (text in Excel), when excel think the data is text type, it will not change any data format (actually no data format for text type). It will directly read the value, which in your case, is '5.65679E+16', you can change the numberformat of the first column in Excel before you run the package, change it to '0' for example, then the excel will read it as '56567876998768900'.

[image]